# using THIS with jquery sortable serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

I have this code

```
$('.contentlist_tosort').sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
        $.post("ajax.php", { pages: $('.contentlist_tosort').sortable('serialize') } );
    }
});
```

But I want it to be generic, since I use class to call sortable, and don't want to put id's on the lists since I have an unknown number of them.

I would like something like this:

```
$('.contentlist_tosort').sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
        $.post("ajax.php", { pages: $(this).sortable('serialize') } );
    }
});
```

But that leaves me with 'undefined' so that is obviously not the way...

Is is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event target would be the UL :

```
$('.contentlist_tosort').sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
        $.post("ajax.php", { pages: $(event.target).sortable('serialize') } );
    }
});
```

Comment: `event.target` would refer to the list item and not the the list.

Comment: @Neal - Nope, `ui.item` refers to the dragged list item, `event.target` to the bound element,  -> [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PASx9/)

Comment: @Neal - It is somewhat strange that `event.target` is in fact the bound element, as that would normally be `this`, and that it is'nt the currently dragged element like you would expect `event.target` to be, but inside sortable, draggable etc. it's actually done like this for some reason!

Comment: Yea... hence my original thought that `event.target` was the list item.... very odd indeed.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I couldn't get it to work at first, then I realized the id tag of the li could not begin with a number( <li id="234"> doesn't work), I couldn't just put the database id on there, I needed a name first like this: <li id="variablename_345">.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ui.item` instead of `this`.

[See the API Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update)

So for example:

```
$('.contentlist_tosort').sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
        var sortable = $(ui.item).parent('ul');
        $.post("ajax.php", { pages: sortable.sortable('serialize') } );
    }
});
```